# Prove that $e^{2x+1}+e^{x}+1/4$ is always greater than 0

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification

Prove that $e^{2x+1}+e^{x}+1/4$ is always greater than $0$

I was thinking of supposing that the function is equal to or less than $0$, and showing that the supposed equation would not work out. How would you solve it? Would it be wiser to prove it using derivatives?

Comment: Do you know that $e^u$ is always $\ge 0$?

Comment: It is the sum of three numbers that are greater than zero

Comment: Well, you have one number ≥ 0 (actually > 0), another number ≥ 0 (actually > 0), and 1/4. And you are asking if the sum is greater than zero?

Comment: Actually the sum is always larger than $1/4$.

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $e^{2x+1} - e^{x} + \frac{1}{4}$ ?

Comment: Is x limited to real numbers?  Can it be complex or imaginary?

Answer (score 4):

start with proving that

$e^x > 0$

$e^x$ is a monotonically increasing function. That is $x>y \implies e^x>e^y$

and $\lim_\limits{x\to-\infty} e^x = 0$

Once you have done that the same thing goes for $e^{2x+1}$

And 1/4 > 0

The sum of 3 positive numbers is positive.

Answer (score 2):

We have $e^{2x+1}+e^{x}+\frac {1}{4}=e \cdot (e^x)^2 + e^x +\frac {1}{4}$. Now use the substitution $e^x=w$ to obtain $ e \cdot w^2 + w + \frac {1}{4}$ and you have to prove that this is greater than $0$.

But we have $ e \cdot w^2 + w + \frac {1}{4} > w^2+w+\frac{1}{4}=(w+\frac{1}{2})^2\geq0$, and we are done.

(We need only the fact that $w=e^x \neq 0$ to prove your question in this way because that is needed to state that we always have $ e \cdot w^2> w^2$).

Comment: Don't you mean > 0 since $ e^x $ > 0 for $ x \in \mathbb{R} $

Comment: @ViktorJeppesen Well, I do not need in this proof the fact that $e^x>0$. Did I use it somewhere in an implicit way?

Comment: nah you only need e^x>-1/2 to conclude >0 at last.

Comment: I'm just saying the conclusion is >0 not >= 0 since that is his question

Answer (score 1):

For any positive $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x^y>0$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$. (If $y$ is positive, then $x^y>0$. If $y=0$, then $x^y=1>0$. If $y$ is negative, then $y=-k$ for some positive $k$ and thus $x^y=x^{-k}=1/x^k>0$.)

Since $e\in \mathbb{R}$ is positive, $e^y> 0$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}$. Now $e^{2x+1}> 0$ and $e^x> 0$ for all $x$, and thus: $$e^{2x+1}+e^x+\frac{1}{4}> 0 .$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming $ x \in \mathbb{R} $

Short answer:  $ e^x > 0 $ for $ x \in \mathbb{R} $ then you have a sum of 3 positive numbers

If you show that this is correct. If would note that $e^x$ is monotone increasing and find it's minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If the expression is correct, then you received the answer concerning the addition of three positive terms.

Let us assume a typo and that the problem is to show that, for any $x$, $$e^{2x+1} - e^{x} + \frac{1}{4}>0$$ So, consider the function $$f(x)=e^{2x+1} - e^{x} + \frac{1}{4}$$ Its first and second derivatives are given by $$f'(x)=2 e^{2 x+1}-e^x=e^x \left(2 e^{x+1}-1\right)$$ $$f''(x)=4 e^{2 x+1}-e^x=e^x \left(4 e^{x+1}-1\right)$$ The first derivative cancels for $$x_*=-1-\log (2)$$ and for this value $$f(x_*)=\frac{e-1}{4 e}>0$$ and $$f''(x_*)=\frac{1}{2 e}$$ So, $x_*$ corresponds to a minimum and $f(x)>0$ for any $x$.

**Edit**

If we had to define the minimum value of $a$ such that $$e^{2x+1} - e^{x} + a>0$$ hods for any $x$, all steps related to derivatives would be the same and $$f(x_*)=a-\frac{1}{4 e}$$ Then the inequality will hold for any $a$ such that $a >\frac{1}{4 e}$.